# RHS Blocklist, Other blocklists and impacts of RHS blocking on similar domains

Tags: dns

I am not very familiar with Blocklists so had a few queries around it.

I have a sub-domain **example.com** which is used to send mass marketing emails i.e. emails are sent from no-reply@example.com. A SPF record has been added under example.com domain to authenticate a mail server to send emails with no-reply@example.com from address.

I also have another sub-domain **example.com.au** (au is Australia - country TLD) which is used for personal, emails i.e. emails are sent from john@example.com.au. A SPF record has been added under example.com.au domain to authenticate a mail server to send emails with john@example.com.au from address.

Now, let's say someone reports me for spamming, and example.com is added to a blocklist like RHSBL. Based on this scenario, I have a few queries:

1. Does it matter which RHSBL i am added to? I suppose gmail, yahoo and hotmail have no standardised RHSBL.
2. Do ISPs have any role to play in RHSBL, or do they only play a role in DNSBL or RBL where IP based blocking is involved?
3. Is there going to be any impact to the reputation of emails that come from @example.com.au just because example.com is added to RHSBL? Or can we consider example.com and example.com.au as different domains (one under gTLD, another under cTLD respectively), and hence there should be no impact?
4. Do SPF records help in improving the chances of a domain name not being added in RHSBL?

Please don't hesitate if you require any clarification on my queries.

Thanks,

John